# BsonDocument to dynamic Expression or in-memory caching of results

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to write a proxy class for `IMongoCollection` so that I can use an in-memory cache for some of the method implementations. The issue, however, is that almost all the filters are of type `FilterDefinition<T>` which means we can call `Render` on them to get a `BsonDocument`. I am wondering if there is a way to convert the filter `BsonDocument` to dynamic Expression so that I can run it against my in-memory `List<T>`. Or maybe there is a better approach to do in-memory caching which I am not aware of. Thank you.

Update:

I was tempted to write a solution as @simon-mourier suggested but the problem with this hacky solution is that C# mongo driver returns `IAsyncCursor<T>` for find operations which is basically a stream of `BsonDocument`s and after each read it is pointing to the last index and disposes itself. And there is no way to reset the stream to its initial position. Which means the following code works the first time but after that, we get an exception of the cursor is at the end of stream and already disposed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DAL.Extensions;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace DAL.Proxies
{
    public static class MongoCollectionProxy
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _instances = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public static IMongoCollection<T> New<T>(IMongoCollection<T> proxy)
        {
            return ((IMongoCollection<T>)_instances.AddOrUpdate(typeof(T), () => new MongoCollectionBaseProxyImpl<T>(proxy)));
        }
    }

    public class MongoCollectionBaseProxyImpl<T> : MongoCollectionBase<T>
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<T> _proxy;

        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

        public MongoCollectionBaseProxyImpl(IMongoCollection<T> proxy)
        {
            _proxy = proxy;
        }

        public override Task<IAsyncCursor<TResult>> AggregateAsync<TResult>(PipelineDefinition<T, TResult> pipeline,
            AggregateOptions options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            return _proxy.AggregateAsync(pipeline, options, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task<BulkWriteResult<T>> BulkWriteAsync(IEnumerable<WriteModel<T>> requests,
            BulkWriteOptions options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            return _proxy.BulkWriteAsync(requests, options, cancellationToken);
        }

        [Obsolete("Use CountDocumentsAsync or EstimatedDocumentCountAsync instead.")]
        public override Task<long> CountAsync(FilterDefinition<T> filter, CountOptions options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            return _proxy.CountAsync(filter, options, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task<IAsyncCursor<TField>> DistinctAsync<TField>(FieldDefinition<T, TField> field,
            FilterDefinition<T> filter, DistinctOptions options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            return _proxy.DistinctAsync(field, filter, options, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override async Task<IAsyncCursor<TProjection>> FindAsync<TProjection>(FilterDefinition<T> filter,
            FindOptions<T, TProjection> options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            // ReSharper disable once SpecifyACultureInStringConversionExplicitly
            return await CacheResult(filter.Render().ToString(), () => _proxy.FindAsync(filter, options, cancellationToken));
        }

        public override async Task<TProjection> FindOneAndDeleteAsync<TProjection>(FilterDefinition<T> filter,
            FindOneAndDeleteOptions<T, TProjection> options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            return await InvalidateCache(_proxy.FindOneAndDeleteAsync(filter, options, cancellationToken));
        }

        public override async Task<TProjection> FindOneAndReplaceAsync<TProjection>(FilterDefinition<T> filter,
            T replacement,
            FindOneAndReplaceOptions<T, TProjection> options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            return await InvalidateCache(_proxy.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(filter, replacement, options,
                cancellationToken));
        }

        public override async Task<TProjection> FindOneAndUpdateAsync<TProjection>(FilterDefinition<T> filter,
            UpdateDefinition<T> update,
            FindOneAndUpdateOptions<T, TProjection> options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            return await InvalidateCache(_proxy.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update, options, cancellationToken));
        }

        public override Task<IAsyncCursor<TResult>> MapReduceAsync<TResult>(BsonJavaScript map, BsonJavaScript reduce,
            MapReduceOptions<T, TResult> options = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            return _proxy.MapReduceAsync(map, reduce, options, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override IFilteredMongoCollection<TDerivedDocument> OfType<TDerivedDocument>()
        {
            return _proxy.OfType<TDerivedDocument>();
        }

        public override IMongoCollection<T> WithReadPreference(ReadPreference readPreference)
        {
            return _proxy.WithReadPreference(readPreference);
        }

        public override IMongoCollection<T> WithWriteConcern(WriteConcern writeConcern)
        {
            return _proxy.WithWriteConcern(writeConcern);
        }

        public override CollectionNamespace CollectionNamespace => _proxy.CollectionNamespace;

        public override IMongoDatabase Database => _proxy.Database;

        public override IBsonSerializer<T> DocumentSerializer => _proxy.DocumentSerializer;

        public override IMongoIndexManager<T> Indexes => _proxy.Indexes;

        public override MongoCollectionSettings Settings => _proxy.Settings;

        private async Task<TResult> CacheResult<TResult>(string key, Func<Task<TResult>> result)
        {
            return _cache.ContainsKey(key) ? (TResult) _cache[key] : (TResult) _cache.AddOrUpdate(key, await result());
        }

        private TResult InvalidateCache<TResult>(TResult result)
        {
            _cache.Clear();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to build a cache based on filters? Why don't you hash the rendered whole BsonDocument to build a key that would define the cache key?

Comment: @SimonMourier that's a very simplistic hack. I'm looking for if there is a way to convert `BsonDocument` to `Linq.Expression` so I can run it against the in-memory collection or there is a way to do in-memory cache using mongo c# driver

Comment: What's the a problem with a simple approach if it does what you want? The rendered BsonDocument is the only common thing between all FilterDefinition derived classes (there are more than 20 of them, and the majority is marked private/internal).

Comment: @SimonMourier no success, I added an update.

Comment: How is CacheResult implemented? You'll have to reimplement IAsyncCursor yourself of course.

Answer (score 3):

if your only concern is creating a decorator class which applies some sort of caching strategy in order to avoid some database access I think that you should try a simpler approach to the problem.

I'm not saying that trying to write a decorator for the interface `IMongoCollection<T>` is wrong per se, I'm just saying that it's not the simplest solution to your problem.

A better approach could be, instead, shrinking your focus to the specific needs of your application. In the following paragraph I'll try to explain my point of view.

Let's suppose that your application must frequently access a User collection and that the user data don't change very often, so that they are good candidates for a simple caching strategy. At that point you can decide to define an abstraction like `IUserRepository` and to shape that abstraction for your application needs. Consider, for instance, this interface definition:

```
public interface IUserRepository 
{
  User GetById(Guid userId);
  ReadOnlyCollection<User> GetAll();
}
```

At this point you will write a concrete implementation which uses MongoDB as a persistence layer:

```
public class MongoUserRepository: IUserRepository 
{
  private readonly IMongoCollection<User> userCollection;

  public MongoUserRepository(IMongoCollection<User> userCollection)
  {
    this.userCollection = userCollection ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userCollection));
  }

  // interface members implementation omitted for simplicity
}
```

Then, you should define a decorator for `IUserRepository` implementing the caching aspect, as follows:

```
public class UserRepositoryCachingDecorator: IUserRepository 
{
  private readonly IUserRepository decoratee;
  private readonly IMemoryCache cache;

  public UserRepositoryCachingDecorator(IUserRepository decoratee, IMemoryCache cache)
  {
    this.decoratee = decoratee ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decoratee));
    this.cache = cache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cache));
  }

  // interface members implementation omitted for simplicity
}
```

In my opinion this is a better approach, because it's much simpler than trying to write a general purpose proxy over `IMongoCollection<T>` and it only requires you to focus on the specific needs of your application.